# Force inner join from EF Cores Include() on optional relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

We changed a relationship from required to optional, now the resulting SQL produced by EF Core's Include() does a left outer join rather than inner join. Problem is that those optional entities have query filters on them that is required.

Let's say we have the following;

```
public class First 
{
    public int? SecondId { get; set; }
}
public class Second 
{
    public First First { get; set; }
    public int ThirdId { get; set; }
}
public class Third
{
    public Second Second { get; set; }
    public string Tenant { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext 
{
    protected readonly string _tenant;
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Third>(p =>
    {
        p.HasQueryFilter(x => Tenant == _tenant);
    });
    ...
}
```

And then we do the following:

```
MyContext.First.Include(p => p.Second).ThenInclude(p => p.Third);
```

This will produce a LEFT OUTER JOIN since the relationship is optional. This will of course then bypass the query filter. Is there a way to make this Include an INNER JOIN instead?

Currently this is solved with adding some more conditions to the where later:

```
.Where(p => p.Second.Third.Tenant == _tenant);
```

But this is undesirable since in some edge cases the _tenant is null and will then give the wrong data.

I know I can flip it around and go for

```
MyContext.Third.Include() ...
```

But this is also undesirable as First in this scenario has a lot of other related data and I don't want to endlessly chain Include().ThenInclude() to the point of ad absurdum.

Can I force inner joins with optional entities? Or do I manually have to write the SQL for this?

Comment: in this line `.Where(p => p.Second.Third.Tenant == _tenant);` you can change it to `.Where(p =>  _tenant != null ?  _tenant.Contain(p.Second.Third.Tenant) : p.Second.Third.Tenant == p.Second.Third.Tenant);` can it solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I force inner joins with optional entities?

You can't. And you *shouldn't*. Because while `inner join` would probably solve your particular case, in general it would filter all dependent entities having `null` FK (e.g. `First.SecondId == null`) which is against the whole concept of *optional* relationship.

The problem I see is that you seem to be trying to use `Include` for filtering. By idea `Include` is what it says - for each entity returned by the query, also include the related data. It's not intended to filter neither the entity nor the related data.

So what you need has to be a query filter.

The actual problem is that EF Core [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) do not support [criteria based on navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#limitations). That's why people in such scenarios break normalization (introduce redundancy) and put `TenantId` property(column) in every entity(table), which allows them to set global filter for each entity.

With that being said, the explicit query filter (`Where`) is currently the only option.

> ```
>    .Where(p => p.Second.Third.Tenant == _tenant);
> ```
>
> But this is undesirable since in some edge cases the _tenant is null and will then give the wrong data.

Well, you just need a correct criteria taking into account the *optional* relationships, for instance

```
.Where(p => p.SecondId == null || p.Second.Third.Tenant == _tenant);
```

But that actually shows the problem of not having `Tenant` on each entity - when `First.SecondId == null`, you can't tell which `Tenant` is owning the `First`.

Comment: Since I'm trying to "replicate" an inner join wouldn't it be:
 .Where(p => p.SecondId != null && p.Second.Third.Tenant == _tenant); ?
Thank you for the detailed answer. I'm guessing the most correct thing to do here is to also add Tenant to entities that are lacking it.

Comment: Sure, if you really want to simulate the `inner join` and filter out the records with `SecondId == null`.

Comment: I've just randomly found this question. I think it would be actually handy to have an overload if the Include method that would take an optional boolean parameter force that would generate an inner join. It would help to generate more efficient queries as doing something as `where(p => p.Children.Any())` generates a subquery and it could be easily and in my opinion more efficiently achievable using an inner join on `Children` property.

Comment: @Vočko In case of single SQL query, probably yes. But now there is specifically "split query" mode for collections, so the main query won't have join at all. Since now we also have "filtered" include, probably the better is just to use `where(p => p.Children.Any())` and let them implement join optimization when translating the query. Pretty much how database query optimizers do nowadays. And it is applicable not only for `Include`, but any correlated subquery inside LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: I understand the complexity of a generic solution, but it is good to give users more options to play with. I'm currently dealing with a big data sets where optimal queries are very important and my hand-written query that uses `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL` condition is about 5 times faster than the best sub-query I was able to generate using EF Core. That's why I'm thinking that having more options would be nice, but I understand that there are probably many gotchas in the generic approach.

Comment: @Vočko I was just saying they could do that when translating the LINQ query. For instance, they know `p.Children` is a join. If you use `from p in ... from c in p.Children` they will generated `inner join`. For `from c in p.Children.DefaultIfEmpty()` or `select new { p.Children, ...}` they generate `left join`. All this is part of the analysis of the query. My point is that they can go further, recognize `where !p.Childern.Any()` in combination with include or collection select, and turn it to `inner join`. No additional hints are needed.

Comment: Sure, they could, it's just not happening (yet). But I have put up a suggestion on their github.